# primefaces 5.0 dynamic tabs can't invoke tabchange

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i'm using p:tabView with dynamic tabs and event listeners support.
look like this:
.xhtml

```
 <h:form id="pageFm">
    <p:tabView scrollable="true"  value="#{MainBean.pagelist}" var="tab" activeIndex="#{MainBean.activeindex}" id="tabview" dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{MainBean.onChange}" />
        <p:tab title="#{tab.pagename}" closable="true">
    <ui:include src="#{tab.pagepath}" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

ManageBean:

```
public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event){
System.out.println("ok");
}
```

When I switch tabs, this method is not called.
i don't know why. 
can give me some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Bean Listener should be

```
public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event){
      System.out.println("ok");
}
```

the seconde problem is related to the use of ui:include with a variable (tab) that shouldn't be avalaible until the render phase, the ui:include tag is build during the restore phase.

Comment: i already change Bean Listener's name.but still can't inverko

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default class name to reference to your managedBean then in your view page you have to set `mainBean` and not `MainBean` .  you have set `listener="#{MainBean.onChange}"` so you have to define a method called `public void onChange(TabChangeEvent)` which will be called when the tab change.

NB: we mean by tabChange the event of select another tab in the tabView , in your case it seems that you have only one tab, try to **add another one** .